# Doctrine findBy with parameters self fetching

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Very often I have to do this `findBy(array('criteria'=> $someObject)`where $someObject is a prepopulated object. My question is: is there a built-in function that given the $someObject id and his entity type fetch him from database and then executes the findBy from above??? Something like this:

```
public function findByDiscriminator($slave, $idSlave, $discriminator, $discriminatorCriteria)
{
    $slaveManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository("AppBundle:$slave");
    $slaveEntity = $slaveManager->find($idSlave);
    return $this->findAllByCriteria(array($discriminatorCriteria => $slaveEntity), 0, 0, $discriminator);
}

public function findAllByCriteria($criteria, $limit = 0, $offset = 0, $repository)
{
    $total = $limit * $offset;
    $start = $limit * ($offset - 1);
    $spamManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository("AppBundle:$repository");
    $spam = $spamManager->findBy($criteria, array(), $total != 0 ? $total : null, $start != 0 ? $start : null);
    return $spam;
}
```

If, lets say, I need to fetch al groceries whose supplier id is 456  I'd query like this
`DAO->findByDiscriminator('SupplierEntity', 456, 'GroceryEntity', 'supplier')` assuming there is a field in GroceryEntity named supplier.

Basically is a findBy() who fetches the criteria from database before querying

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no such built-in wrappers for findBy method provided by doctrine. You can define them in some base class and then inherit it by your doctrine data access objects which will finally bring reusability to your code that you are looking for.

Comment: That is what I currently do, just wanted to be sure. Thanks a lot. Upvoting (if my reputation allows it)